# How to change foreground colour of description of uwp Input controls

Tags: uwp

I validate the input of the textbox in the code behind file and sometimes it involves database things.

If the error occurs in validation stage, I set some error message to textbox's description.

What I want to do is to change that description foreground colour and the border to red.

How can I do that?

Comment: Has your issue been solved? If yes, you could mark a useful answer, which will help others that face the same question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a TextBox, it will use the default template, its style is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
..
<ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" Grid.Row="2" x:Load="False"/>
…
</Style>
```

As you can see, there is a `ContentPresenter` named DescriptionPresenter, which controls the Description property of TextBox. So you could use [Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=net-5.0) to find this ContentPresenter and access it, then you could change its Foreground. For changing the border color of TextBox, you could use the `BorderBrush` property of TextBox directly. Please refer to the following code.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var contentPresenter=FindChild<ContentPresenter>(myTextbox);         
            contentPresenter.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            myTextbox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

        public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child is T typedChild)
                {
                   var name= child.GetValue(NameProperty);
                    if (name.ToString()== "DescriptionPresenter") 
                    {
                        return typedChild;
                    }  
                }
                var inner = FindChild<T>(child);
                if (inner != null)
                {
                    return inner;
                }
            }
            return default;
        }
```